# OpenGL - Render scene as Mercator/Cylindrical

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pyopengl

I have a scene built out of some triangles. In order to render it to an equirectangular image I just rendered it 6 times to 6 cubes, copied them to memory and using some cube2sphere code transformed it to an equirectangular image.

Is there a way to do that directly in the shader and save the time it takes to do this calculation on the CPU?

I found all kind of examples like some [here](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4tjGW1) but it seems to require a precalculated cubemap. And in my case I don't have it in advance, but want to generate it as part of the rendering.

> **Note:** I also need to keep the depth map. So far I just converted it as
>   well using the same sphere2cube (and a little factoring dependent on
>   the angle) and it was fine.
>
> **Note2:** I actually want Cylindrical/Mercator projection, and not
>   equirectangular. But it's not very important.

Comment: I think you could do the projection in Vertex shader but you might have problems with crossing the 0 deg longitude and/or +/-90deg latitude barrirers. So you might have to split your mesh by those to avoid artifacts. So you just convert from 3D into 2D texture position in vertex and in fragment just render the output color ...